# Xamarin.Forms String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add a user in my SQLite database.

```
var usercd = result[0].USERCD;
var position = result[0].POSITION;
var usergroup = result[0].USERGRP;
var pwd = result[0].PASSWORD;
var expiredate = result[0].EXPIRYDT;
var lastedit = result[0].LSTPWDDT;
var inactive = result[0].INACTIVE;
var expd = DateTime.Parse(expiredate);
var ledt = DateTime.Parse(lastedit);
var lastsync = DateTime.Parse(DefaultSettings.current_datetime);
var lastupdate = DateTime.Parse(DefaultSettings.current_datetime);

var insertdata = new UserTable
{
    USERCD = usercd,
    POSITION = position,
    USERGRP = usergroup,
    PASSWORD = pwd,
    EXPIRYDT = expd,
    LSTPWDDT = ledt,
    INACTIVE = inactive,
    LASTSYNC = lastsync,
    LASTUPDATED = lastupdate
};
```

Here are the values of the **date time variables**:
- **expiredate = "30-03-2020 12:00:00"** but the variable **expd = "30/03/2020 12:00:00"**
- **lastedit = "18-09-2019 12:00:00"** but the variable **ledt = "18/09/2019 12:00:00"**
- **current_datetime = "27-09-2019 08:08:00"** but the variables **lastupdate and lastsync = "27/09/2019 08:08:00"**

I've tried using **DateTime.Parse, DateTime.ParseExact and Convert.ToDateTime** still I am getting the same error every time.

**Edit 1**
Here is what I have tried so far,

> DateTime.ParseExact(expiredate, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

**Edit 2**
Here is the JSON file where I get my values.

> **[{"Message":"Correct Credentials","USERCD":"BIS1","POSITION":"IT","USERGRP":"IT","PASSWORD":"password","LSTPWDDT":"18-09-2019 12:00:00","EXPIRYDT":"30-03-2020 12:00:00","INACTIVE":"0"}]**

Here the error I am getting:

> **System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime**

But here is the thing, when testing the function on a standard build meaning just debugging it in my phone it is working however, when I archived the app and turn it into an APK and installed it the function of inserting data is not working and getting that error.

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` *can* do what you need, but *how* you used it matters and you haven't shown that.

Comment: or specify a culture

Comment: @madreflection I tried it on my other phone it is working how ever when I used my galaxy s6 edge which is a android 7.0 and android 8.1.0 it is not working

Comment: It's not the value that I'm asking about. It's the source of the data. Database? REST service? Wh is it a string and not already a `DateTime`?

Comment: @madreflection its DateTime all of the variables with DateTime.Parse is a DateTime

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: @madreflection I get my data using JSON please see my edited question

Comment: Do you control the generation of the JSON?

Comment: @fbiazi I used PHP to generate the JSON file, It is queried from my Oracle database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is probably being generated using local culture, so you get one thing when testing and another when running.

Try to generate it with `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`

If possible always use this format, it may prevent a LOT of problems.

EDIT:
On PHP you can use `date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')` to format a date with time this way.

Reference on PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Where do I use this format in my JSON or in my app or both?

Comment: Both, an example of formating this way on PHP is `date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');` directly from https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php adapt it to your needs

Comment: Why does this format yyyy-MM-dd prevents a lot problems? just to clarify

Comment: Read up ISO 8601 format and the reason for its existence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601  https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html  If I had to give you *one word*: **unambiguous**.

Comment: Does not depend on culture, you can directly order it in text form and expect to be in corectly order, and all of the numbers on the format are from a bigger value to a more specific year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, fractions. You can put it on file names and order it. You can search a lot of data searching for month 3 of year 2020 and easily find what you want, etc.

Comment: But the more important reason is what madreflection said in one word!

Comment: @fbiazi I tied it still in my Galaxy 6s Edge I am getting the error

Comment: The better thing to do is to print a message or throw an alert with the evolved parameters so you can narrow the possibilities.